# Android Studio 0.5.9 error code 42

Tags: android, android-studio

Everytime I try to import a project from eclipse I receive Error like that

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

> Error: Failed to run command:
>       D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe s -i C:\projects\ZwallU\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\filgoal.png -o C:\projects\ZwallU\app\build\res\all\debug\drawable-hdpi\filgoal.png
>   Error Code:
>       42
>   Output:
>       libpng error: Not a PNG file

there's nothing wrong when working with this file on eclipse .. anyone has a solution for this error ?

Comment: Try opening the file with any photo editor, and save a new copy of it. This should regenerate the png

Comment: I did try that and it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you have a problem with the file filgoal.png...

> C:\projects\ZwallU\app\build\res\all\debug\drawable-hdpi\filgoal.png
>   Error Code: 42 Output: libpng error: Not a PNG file

Open it with a editor and save as with PNG selected. 
Maybe, the file is in a another format like JPEG.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was getting this issue and was not able to fine solution and finally your answer solved my issue...