# Android gradle build Error "finished with non-zero exit value 42" , what does it mean and how do i fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run an older project on what i think is the latest version of android studio. When I attempt to run or debug the app i get 2 error messages. I have Google this and found no viable solution.

error 1

Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Android Studio\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42

error 2

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> E:\tuts\Developing Android Apps {AM}\Exercise Files\Ex_Files_DevelopAndroidApp_EssT\Ex_Files_DevelopAndroidApp_EssT\Exercise Files\Solutions\04_Layouts\RegistrationSolution\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-mdpi\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Android Studio\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42

What do the errors mean and how do i fix them? 
[image: here you can see the Android Studio]

I tried closing and opening and android studio think it may help somehow 
[image: Image of Event Log]

Comment: Can you put all log?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065282/android-studio-0-5-9-error-code-42

Comment: @Hyperion i added the log now

Comment: @isma3l tried this with photoshop, fireworks and paint they fixed these  errors but created this error "The project may need to be synced with Gradle files." After syncing i had the same the previous errors back

Comment: check the existing of "E:\Android Studio\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio has this problem sometimes.

You have to check by refactoring the image format to jpg, jpeg etc to see which works for you.

It is said that due to the original image being of another format this problem occurs but I checked by changing the format of the original image also.

No possible reason could be explained.

In my case changing my PNG to JPG removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems about google support library

Try clean project and/or make sure following line exists in build.gradle  dependencies section

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'`